# Where are NetworkManager's WiFi settings stored?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wifi, networkmanager, xubuntu

I remember the days of playing with /etc/$WE/wpa_supplicant.conf to try and force a semi-secure network on a debian based system, but now on to xubuntu, I haven't needed to do any *.conf-ing in a while (in terms of networking)

As such, I'm interested to know; How do the nm gui's store network information? Can this be backed up or exported as a wpa_supplicant.conf file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using NetworkManager (which, I believe Xubuntu does), it should be in `/etc/NetworkManager/nm-system-settings.conf`.

There is more information about it here: http://live.gnome.org/NetworkManager/SystemSettings.

Comment: Nearly right; mine were in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/$networkname`. Thanks!

Comment: in the `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` are stored only system-wide a.k.a. `Available to all users` connections. The user's personal ones are stored in his home dir `~/.gconf/system/networking/connections`.

Answer (score 5):

On Fedora wifi settings are stored in directory /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts. Each wifi network has two files ifcfg-SSID and keys-SSID