# Exporting NetworkManager configurations

Tags: fedora, configuration, networkmanager

I am using Fedora 19, there is no `~/.gconf/networking/NetworkManager` directory, and system-wide `/etc/NetworkManager` has no files required.

I want to export **my user**'s `NetworkManager` configurations, that is Wireless, VPN credentials (ip, username, password) to a file, or at least find the directory where they are stored in Fedora 19. How to do that?

Comment: Duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22367/where-are-networkmanagers-wifi-settings-stored

Comment: it's for fedora, not for ubuntu, i don't see enough similarities for considering this post a duplicate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Fedora seems that `/etc/NetworkManager` doesn't work, it's always empty. Take a look at `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts`, I found mine here.

Comment: Are these system wide or user? The OP wants his "user" configs.

Comment: it's really there named `ifcfg-home`, but without password field (data) what i also want to export

Comment: @loofda - It must be kept somewhere else as well, I don't have that in my directory.

Comment: @loofda on my system the keys are in the same directory.

Comment: thanks! i've found it, it was in separate file `keys-home`

Answer (score 1):

If you run the following command you can determine what files NetworkManager is using to store it's config info:

```
$ sudo lsof | grep NetworkMa
```

You can also list out the contents of the NetworkManager package to see where things are kept (v0.8.5.92):

```
$ rpm -ql NetworkManager
...
/etc/NetworkManager
/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
/etc/NetworkManager/VPN
/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
/etc/dbus-1/system.d/NetworkManager.conf
/etc/dbus-1/system.d/nm-avahi-autoipd.conf
/etc/dbus-1/system.d/nm-dhcp-client.conf
/etc/dbus-1/system.d/nm-dispatcher.conf
/etc/dbus-1/system.d/nm-ifcfg-rh.conf
```

Comment: Won't work for files that are no longer open.