# How to export and migrate NetworkManager settings to new system?

Tags: networking, networkmanager

How to export and migrate NetworkManager settings to new system?

Use cases are:

- reinstalling a machine
- moving network configuration from laptop to desktop system (or vice-versa)

All settings should be migrated, that includes:

- default and custom network connections
- wifi connections with passwords
- VLAN configurations
- VPN configurations (with keys if possible)

I checked on Arch wiki and it there is nothing on migration, so I'm asking you guys and gals here.

Answer (score 29):

Each connection configured in NetworkManager is stored in a file in

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
```

Usually, you can copy needed files from a machine to another (by root, of course).

**Warning**: some configuration file could reference external resources. E.g. in one of my openvpn files I have a line like `cert=/home/andcoz/somedir/somefile.crt`. You need to copy any referred file.

**Warning 2**: passwords will NOT be on those files by default. see [docs](https://www.networkmanager.dev/docs/api/latest/nm-settings-dbus.html#secrets-flags). Instead lines such as `private-key-flags=1`, it means the password is saved in your secret agent (for example `kde wallet`). In most GUI clients, this is controlled by the drop down under each password "Store password for this user only (encrypted)". If you change to the other value, the `-flags` value will change to `0` and passwords will be on those files (which are read by root only).

Comment: This answer is incomplete. NetworkManager assigns a UUID to each system connection that appears to be based on the MAC address of the interface. If you change hardware, NetworkManager won't use old system connections because the UUID no longer matches what it expects.

Comment: I checked directory /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections on my laptop and I only see vpn connections there. But I don't see any wired or wifi settings there. I'll try moving over one vpn connection and report back if this works or not. So if it works this answers 1/4 of the question. Thanks.

Comment: @divestoclimb is there some guide that explains how to rename UUID from old system to new one's ?

Comment: @divestoclimb is right, these connections won't be picked up if you migrate to new hardware, only for a reinstall on the same hardware this will work. I'd love to know a solution here, just like valentt!

Comment: The UUID is only a random generated identifier. You have to be sure that each connection has a unique identifier (on each machine).

Comment: Perhaps, you'd have some problem on different hardware if your configuration file has some line like "mac-address". I usually do not have that line but, if you have that kind of line, you'll have to change the hardware address to the right value on that machine. Use `ip link` to check the hardware address of your devices.

Comment: In my VPN conf file I don't see any external reference nor MAC address. But when I copy it to a new system (both are Ubuntu 20.04) and reboot, the file is not seen by `nmcli con`.

Answer (score 17):

As mentioned by others, Wi-Fi connection files in `system-connections` directory have the interface MAC address included. This need to match your current setup hence the procedure is:

1. copy all files from old machine to new machine from/to directory:

   ```
   /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
   ```
2. change MAC address entry in each file from old MAC to new MAC. As root:

   ```
   cd /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
   sed -i -e 's/<old mac>/<new mac>/ *
   ```
3. Just in case, restart network manager:

   ```
   systemctl restart NetworkManager
   ```

Old mac you may check from any of the files you copied, new mac if unsure you can check with `ip link` (or from the file that likely got created when you installed your system for the connection you used to copy the files).

Note: above assumes you had a single Wi-Fi interface in both your old an new setup, but the same logic should work with multiple interfaces.

Comment: What is the line of MAC for VPN conf files? I only see UUID. How can I re-generate new UUID on a new machine?

Comment: In Arch based distro case, restart *NetworkManager* solves **saved network list problem**

Answer (score 5):

Wireless settings (at least on Fedora) are kept in this directory:

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts
```

There are two files per wifi connection. First file is named `ifcfg-YOURSSID` contains wifi network settings and `keys-YOURSSID` contains wireless network password.

Also there is a related question that explains this:
[Where are NetworkManager's WiFi settings stored?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22367/where-are-networkmanagers-wifi-settings-stored/400821#400821)

Comment: Why is Fedora storing them differently than all the others?

Comment: A good reference is [man nm-settings-ifcfg-rh](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nm-settings-ifcfg-rh.html)

Answer (score 5):

The following worked for me on **ubuntu:20.10**

**Copy the contents of `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` over**.

Make sure that the **`permissions=user:newusername:;` matches your running user** (the one under which you want to use the vpn - `echo $( whoami )` can help)

Next make sure you have the **correct packages installed**.
If you are using `openvpn` then you need

```
network-manager-openvpn
network-manager-openvpn-gnome
```

**You will also need the correct `service-type` packages installed**.
For example when using `service-type=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.l2tp`
Then you will need to install `l2tp` for network manager

**And finally** what I had problem with is **permissions** on the files in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`
For me, the files need these permissions:

`-rw------- 1 root root`

When I copied the files I had 775 permissions with my user as owner on them which prevented NetworkManager from using them for some reason.

Comment: THIS is the complete answer

Comment: I'm afraid it's not complete either. It misses external files (keys and certs), passwords stored elsewhere, MAC/UUIDs not matching... the list is still probably incomplete.

Answer (score 3):

The other posts are right, but there are minor changes to some points.

The answers are kept in

```
/etc/Networkmanager/system-connections
```

You can remove the line `mac-address` or change it via

```
cd /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
sed -i -e 's/<old mac>/<new mac>/' *
```

You can get the new mac adress via

```
ip a
```

Depending on the storage where You kept the files, the file rights may be wrong, just set them  via:

```
chmod 0600 *
chown root:root *
```

Finally restart Network Manager

```
systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

Works the same under ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 2):

It took me too long to figure this out, but you can export individual things (like VPN settings) using `nmcli`:

```
# List connections
nmcli connection

# Export one
nmcli connection export ConnectionName > yourfile
```

This works no matter where your config files are, though I think there's no way to export more than one at a time. Unfortunately this doesn't appear to retain at least password credentials - it may retain certificate ones.

Comment: Usage: nmcli connection export { ARGUMENTS | help }

ARGUMENTS := [id | uuid | path] <ID> [<output file>]

Export a connection. Only VPN connections are supported at the moment.
The data are directed to standard output or to a file if a name is given. (This at least for Centos/rocky 8.4)

Comment: It doesn't do much, only grabs what is in system-connections. For OpenVPN connections in particular, keys and certs are left out so it is basically useless.

Answer (score 0):

Use the connection show interface name and redirect to a file. First run con show to get the name/UUID

```
nmcli con show 
nmcli con show eth0 > yourfile
```